# How do I update bank for each person in python?

Tags: python

This is what I have so far. I want to update bank for each player but I don't know how to connect each player to their bank?

I want it to look like this:

```
How many players are in the game: 4
Player 1 you have $1000
What is your bet: 65
Player 2 you have $1000
What is your bet: 7
Player 3 you have $1000
What is your bet: 88
Player 4 you have $1000
What is your bet: 8
```

While on the side the code counts how much each player now has on a side, I don't want it printed just kept in the memory for later use. I think I'm doing mine wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea, you want to use a list, with an element for each player.

You can initialize a list with $1000 for each player with:

```
bank = [1000] * players
```

Now, you can update each bank separately:

```
bank[i] = bank[i] - bet
print bank[i]
```

So you would have something like:

```
"""
Player limit of up to 7 players. Has to be more than one player.
"""
players = int(raw_input("How many players are in the game: "))
while players == "" or players == 0 or players == 1 or players > 7:
    players = int(raw_input("How many players are in the game: "))
bank = [1000] * players
for i in range (players):
    print "Player " + str(i+1) + " you have " + "$" + str(bank)
    bet = int(raw_input("What is your bet: "))
    while bet <= 0 or bet > 1000:
        bet = int(raw_input("What is your bet: "))

    bank[i] = bank[i] - bet
    print bank[i]
```

I am not entirely sure what `bankinventory` is attempting to keep track of.

Comment: do I have to make a new loop for the bank? or do I just include a j loop under the players loop?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to accomplish.  If a player's bet just affects them, you don't need to loop at all.  You use the player number 'i', as the index into the bank.  So, player number `i`s bank is bank[i].  Make sense?  I've added more code based on yours.

Comment: oh I see now, I just needed an idea of how to do that. I will be doing more with it later and will probably adjust things a little. Thank you very much.